# why does klass.create(donor) always create a new donor while donors_controller#create does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I go to my donors_controller#create from a form in my view, it will update a record if it matches on ID or the collection of columns in my find_by_*

But if I call that create from a different controller, it always creates new records.

My donors_controller has a create method with:

```
  def create
    # need to find donor by id if given, else use find_or_create_by_blahblahblah
    unless @donor = Donor.find_by_id(params[:donor][:id])
      @donor = Donor.find_or_initialize_by_company_and_prefix1_and_first_name1_and_last_name1_and_address1(params[:donor])
    end
    if @donor.new_record?  
       ...
    else
       ...
    end
  end
```

My other controller has :

```
 class_name = 'Donor'
 klass = ActiveRecord.const_get(class_name)  
   ... code to populate myarray with appropriate values
 klass.create(myarray)
```

I am pretty sure myarray is populated with the necessary params since it creates valid records with everything in the right place.  I can even run the same record through more than once and it creates duplicate (except for the Donor.id of course) records.

What am I doing wrong here?

I noticed I could do this in my other controller and it works, but why can't I call the create from the donors_controller and have it work without always creating a new record?

```
#klass.create(myarray)
@mydonor = klass.find_or_initialize_by_company_and_prefix1_and_first_name1_and_last_name1_and_address1(myarray) 
@mydonor.save
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question is very unclear and hard to follow, so i'm not sure my answer will match your needs. It seems you're confusing a controller#create method with a model#create method.

**On the model :** it is a class method

`create`, as its name implies, instantiates a `new` object of the `Donor` class and calls `save` on it:

```
@donor = Donor.create
# is the same thing as
@donor = Donor.new
@donor.save
```

Active Record uses `new_record?` to determine if it should perform an insert or an update on the db when you call `save` on an instanciated record. So with `create` it will *always* be an insert since the record is inevitably new ; but if you call `save` on a record retrieved from the database, it will be updated.

**On a controller :** it is an instance method

... but does not directly manages persistence, that's the role of the model. It is an action for this controller ; it is called `create` for the sake of [RESTful naming conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions). `create` is called on a controller instance when a POST request is routed to it ; its purpose is to manage that request, which often (but not always) means to *create records using the appropriate model*, using `YourModelName.new` or `YourModelName.create`.

so it is absolutely possible (but not advisable) to do:

```
class DonorsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # only works well if params[:donor][:id] is nil,
    # will raise an error if a record with the  
    # same id exists in the database
    @donor = Donor.create(params[:donor]) 
  end
end
```

as it is generally needed to perform several operations before saving your record, and to check if save is successful, the process is broken down :

```
class DonorsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @donor = Donor.new(params[:donor])
    # perform operations on @donor (instance of Donor class)
    if @donor.save # save returns true if successfully performed, false either
      # all is fine
    else
      # @donor could not be saved
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You are correct. I was confused on the difference between the create in my controller on using Donor.create.   I thought calling Donor.create found the controller and used the create method there.  I see now how it works.  thank you!